# How to properly detach firebase db child event listener?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to detach this listener:

```
listenForNew() {
    const firebase = this.props.firebase;
    let newestDate = new Date().getTime();
    if(this.state.subitiq.length !== 0) {
        newestDate = this.state.subitiq[this.state.subitiq.length-1].date;
    }
    console.log("listening after date " + (newestDate+1));
    const ref = firebase.database().ref().child('subitiq').orderByChild('date').startAt(newestDate+1).on('child_added', snapshot => {
        console.log("added new subitie with key " + snapshot.key);
        let subitie = snapshot.val();
        subitie.key = snapshot.key;
        let subitiq = this.state.subitiq.slice(0);
        subitiq.push(subitie);
        let showedSubitiq = this.state.showedSubitiq.slice(0);
        showedSubitiq.push(subitie);
        this.setState({subitiq: subitiq, showedSubitiq: showedSubitiq});
        //console.log(subitie);
    }, error => {
        console.error(error);
    });

    this.addRefListener(ref, 'subitiq', 'child_added');
} // listenForNew()
```

This is addRefListener():

```
addRefListener(ref, refPath, listener) {
    let refs = this.state.refs;
    let listeners = this.state.listeners;
    let refPaths = this.state.refPaths;
    refs.push(ref);
    refPaths.push(refPath);
    listeners.push(listener);
    this.setState({refPaths: refPaths, refs: refs, listeners: listeners});
} // addRefListener()
```

And this is how I am trying to detach:

```
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.componentCleanup();
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentCleanup); // remove the event handler for normal unmounting
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentCleanup);
//...
}
    componentCleanup() { // this will hold the cleanup code
        // whatever you want to do when the component is unmounted or page refreshes
        const firebase = this.props.firebase;
        for(let i=0; i<this.state.refs.length; i++) {
            try {
                firebase.database().ref().child(this.state.refPaths[i]).off(this.state.listeners[i]);
                console.log("removed listener at '" + this.state.refPaths[i] + "' on '" + this.state.listeners[i] + "' #1 block");
            } catch(er) {
                console.log("error block #1");
                console.error(er);
            }

            try {
                firebase.database().ref().child(this.state.refPaths[i]).off(this.state.listeners[i], this.state.refs[i]);
                console.log("removed listener at '" + this.state.refPaths[i] + "' on '" + this.state.listeners[i] + "' #2 block");
            } catch(er) {
                console.log("error block #2");
                console.error(er);
            }

            try {
                this.state.refs[i].off(this.state.listeners[i]);
                console.log("removed listener at '" + this.state.refPaths[i] + "' on '" + this.state.listeners[i] + "' #3 block");
            } catch(er) {
                console.log("error block #3");
                console.error(er);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get error on block #3 (this.state.refs[i].off is not a function), block #1 and block #2 don't give errors, but actually they don't detatch.
I have found many questions and tried multiple things and still I don't understand what do I do wrong?

Comment: Wat is the error

Comment: this.state.refs[i].off is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following line, because of the [`on(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#on) function, the object you have called `ref` is not a Reference/Query object, but actually the snapshot callback function (`snapshot => { /* ... */ }`).

```js
const ref = firebase.database().ref().child('subitiq').orderByChild('date').startAt(newestDate+1).on('child_added', snapshot => { /* ... */ }, error => { /* ... */ });
```

To get the Reference/Query object, you must split the lines into the following:

```js
let queryRef = firebase.database().ref().child('subitiq').orderByChild('date').startAt(newestDate+1);
let callback = queryRef.on('child_added', snapshot => { /* ... */ }, error => { /* ... */ });
```

Once you have both of these, you can call `addListenerUnsubscribe` which is my version of your `addRefListener` function.

```js
addListenerUnsubscribe(queryRef, 'child_added', callback);
```

Later when your component is being cleaned up, you would simply call `unsubscribeAllListeners()` like so:

```
componentCleanup() {
  unsubscribeAllListeners();
}
```

```js
addListenerUnsubscribe(ref, eventType, callback, name) {
    let listeners = this.state.listeners;
    listeners.push({ref: ref, eventType: eventType, cb: callback, name: name});
    this.setState({listeners}); // this seems unneccessary
}

unsubscribeAllListeners() {
    let listeners = this.state.listeners;
    listeners.forEach((listener) => {
      listener.ref.off(listener.eventType, listener.callback);
    });
    this.setState({listeners: []});
}
```

With the above code, you could also remove a group of listeners by name if desired.

```js
unsubscribeListenersByName(name) {
    let listeners = this.state.listeners;
    let remaining = listeners.filter((listener) => {
      if (name !== listener.name) return true; // keep
      listener.ref.off(listener.eventType, listener.callback);
    });
    // remaining is an array of still active listeners
    this.setState({listeners: remaining});
}
```

References:

- [`Query#on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#on)
- [`Query#off()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#off)
- [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

> You can remove a **single listener** by passing it as a parameter to off(). Calling off() on the location with no arguments removes all listeners at that location.

For example if you have this listener:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref().child('subitiq').orderByChild('date').startAt(newestDate+1).on('child_added', snapshot =>
```

Then to detach it you need to use the same reference and do:

```
ref.off('child_added');
```

Also `off()` is a method inside `Reference`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#off